# Restarting mysqld on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I'm trying to restart my mysqld process on CentOS 6.6. I have root access to the server and when I run `top`, this is the first line:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3874 mysql     15   0 2859m 336m 7188 S 120.5 16.4  74730:50 mysqld
```

Clearly there is an issue there (and I may need to increase the DB server since it's maxing out) but the first step I want to take is to put the process through a power cycle to restart it since it hasn't been restarted in a very long time.

I've tried as root to do many different processes:

```
service mysqld restart (I get service not found)
```

If I run `which mysqld` I get `/usr/sbin/mysqld` . I tried:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld restart
```

That didn't work. I tried:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

That didn't work. Do I need to be logged in as the mysql user to do this? I figured root would be able to do this but I guess I just can't find the correct way to restart the server.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try `killall mysqld` first? Or `killall -s 9 mysqld`.

Comment: do you actually have the init script in `/etc/init.d`? what error did it throw (if any?)

Answer (score 1):

The correct command to restart a MySql service is:

```
$ service mysql restart
```

Please confirm the status of the service by typing `$ service mysql status`

Comment: Service not found.

Comment: I think re-installing msql might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to copy back the init script for MySQL server from source file.

Take a look to this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-server.html